# How to efficiently match two array values in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the best way to match two array axis in Python, most likely using Numpy.
To be more precise :
I have`C` which is a H x W x L  matrix and `D` which is a H x W matrix. H and W are the height and width of an image, and L is, for example, the set of luminance that can be displayed in the image (**0** to **100** for example). `D` contains the real luminance of the pixel.

I want to add all the values linked to the luminance in the third axis of `C` of the pixels that match the luminance in the **D** matrix, e.g. the value in the `D` matrix would tell me which index to use to get the value in the `C` matrix.

Of course, I can do this easily with three loops :

```py
sum = 0

for row in range(H) :
  for column in range(W) :
    for luminance in range(L) :
      if luminance == D[row, column] :
        sum += C[row, column, luminance]
        break
```

But this is not efficient. I am trying to find a way to do this using numpy, something like this :

```py
import numpy as np

sum = np.sum(C[:, :, np.where(C[:,:] == [D[:,:]])[0][0]))
```

I do not know if this is supposed to work.
I think there might be a way using the **meshgrid** function to loop through the pixels easily, and correctly have the match by calling

```py
import numpy as np

sum = np.sum(np.meshgrid(range(H), range(W), f(D)))
```

where **f(D)** has to be something to do with the **D** matrix.

Well, this is what I tried so far, thank you for your help as always !

Comment: I think np.sum(C[:,:,0] == D) should suffice

Comment: The third axis contains values between 0 and L-1 : I want to add those values based on the fact that they match the ones in D (pixel to pixel). Here, I would only add ones I think, as it would return a boolean matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bumping this thread to include an answer using `numpy.meshgrid`.

One would be able to do that with :

```py
import numpy as np

lines, columns = np.meshgrid(range(H), range(W), indexing='ij')

sum = np.sum(C[lines, columns, D])
```

With that, the value in `D` tells which index to use in `C` to get the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just sum all values of `D`? Is there a chance that the luminance in `C` won't appear in `D`, is that why?

Anyway, another way of accomplishing what you want is by repeating values of `C` to match the shape of `D`, and then summing only the values that match, provided that each pixel of C doesn't have duplicate values.

```
D_repeated = np.repeat(D[:, :, np.newaxis], L, axis=2)
sum = np.sum(C[C==D_repeated])
```

Comment: I think I was a bit misleading and did get things mixed up : I have other values than the luminance as the third axis : the matrix D would only get me the index that would eventually tell me which value to sum for this pixel. I'll edit my message.

Comment: I think I understood. Nevertheless, if you create an auxiliary matrix, with the same dimensions of C, but with index values as third dimensions. You can sum them as `sum = np.sum(C[C_auxiliary==D_repeated])`

Comment: And you can get this `C_auxiliary` with `np.indices`. It would be the `z` dimension of: `x, y, z = np.indices((H, W, L))`